# Using ArcPy to Remove Join?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins, error-000800, pythonwin, error-000229

I am trying to remove a join in arcpy and have been all over the forums and help topics but cannot get my script to remove the join.

I have tried many combinations of inputs to the remove join but to no avail.

```
Name94 = "C:\\a\\b\\c\\input1.shp"
Name95 = "C:\\a\\b\\c\\input2.shp"
TablesView = "C:\\a\\b\\c\\TablesView.lyr"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Name94, TablesView)
arcpy.AddJoin_management(TablesView, "Buf_Units", Name95, "Units", "KEEP_ALL")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(TablesView, "Buf_Area", "[Area]", "VB", "") 
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(TablesView, "Buf_Units")
```

This yields the error:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000800: The value is not a member of  | Input2.
Failed to execute (RemoveJoin).
```

In place of buf_units I have tried:

```
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(TablesView, "'"+Name95.rstrip(".shp")+"'")
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(TablesView)
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(TablesView, "input2")
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(TablesView, Name95)
arcpy.RemoveJoin_management(TablesView, "units")
```

The previous error is the result of most of these tries but when it is not it is:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000229: Cannot open C:\a\b\c\TablesView.lyr
Failed to execute (RemoveJoin).
```

I am running python 2.7, 64bit, 10.1 arcgis

Comment: Are you running this inside of ArcMap ? or running it from an IDE? Cannot open errors happened to me when I forgot to specify a working environment.

Comment: I am running in pythonwin. The code above is just a snipet. I have a working environment set. TablesView is implicitly defined as well (C:\\a\\b\\c\\TablesView.lyr)
I had to implicitly create layer files for my make feature layer operations to work in a loop.

Comment: I think your question will be much easier to answer if you edit it to focus on why just one of your examples is not working.  Taking your first example, what are the variable `name94`, `name95` and `TablesView` set to when you run it?  I recommend adding print statements to one of your code snippets to show us along with the precise error message that is thrown by that code snippet.

Comment: From your very first example, simply try:   Name95.rstrip(".shp")  (without the addition of quotes).

Comment: @KHibma tried it and got error 000800. Parameters are not valid. The value is not a member of | ISOstep95

Comment: It looks like the symptoms emerging from your tests are changing so I think you should **edit** your question to show exactly what code you are running to produce this error.  I think printing out variable values rather than leaving us to guess what they may be set to will make this very easy to answer.

Comment: You used "Buf_Units" when you join table,But when you RemoveJoin,you used "ISOStep9".I think it is reason.

Comment: Your text TableView in three of your statments needs to be surrounded by single or double quotes e.g. arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Name94, 'TablesView')

Comment: TablesView is a defined layer file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code doesn't work because [MakeFeatureLayer_management()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000) creates a *layer* (in memory) , not a *layer file* (.lyr).

Just replace your TablesView variable, e.g.

```
TablesView = "TablesView"
```

and you shouldn't get that error anymore.

Comment: Of all the combinations I tried, I did not try that. That did it! Thanks. arcpy.RemoveJoin_management("TablesView")